# How to use the CodeName one Api for remote automated building

Tags: bash, api, build, remote-access, codenameone

I want to take generated code created by me for building final user mobile applications of my dessire. What i Api should i use for that? With a proffesional plan may i do multiples scripted builds?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use automated remote scripting to do this since it violates the terms of service specifically disallowing more than one developer per build.

You will need to sign a contract with Codename One to get special access to the servers which will allow you to build in such a way.

Comment: Exactly, so whats the paid plan should pay me or my company? In the end it would be only one app building at the time, i just dont want to upload it by self but with a bot that does it automatically

Comment: If you are looking for continuous integration, this will make it into the enterprise plan in the coming months. If you are looking to build an app wizard you will need to sign a custom contract based on usage since the enterprise license is per developer.